# Break an infinite loop in Hub

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to break an infinite loop in signalr hub invoked method, which reads com port data.

I'm trying break a loop by invoking another hub method, which set to false loop condition. But, it seems method is not invoked because logger didn't log anything.

Is technically it possible? If possible is it a good idea infinitely looping inside hub method?

```
    private bool Continue { get; set; } = true;

    public async Task Start()
    {
        while (Continue)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("data").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    public async Task Stop()
    {
        Continue = false;
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("stopped").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `hub`? SignalR? Azure Event Hub? Some other hub? As for the infinite loop, without looking at the code it's impossible to guess what's going on. Perhaps you didn't even call that method?

Comment: I mean SignalR, editing now. I'm asking only for posibility.

Comment: No, it is invoked if call it firstly before that method which have a loop

Comment: What is invoked, what is called? Instead of describing your code, post it. Descriptions can't be compiled, checked or tested

Comment: Post has been edited. Code is added.

Comment: Did you call `Start` ? In any case, global flags aren't thread safe. All task-related examples show using a CancellationTokenSource and a CancellationToken instead of global flags

Comment: Yes, but then cannot break a loop with help of a "Stop" method.

Comment: Because global fields aren't thread-safe. Use a CancellationTokenSource and CancellationToken instead. `SendAsync` already accepts this parameter and so do all async SignalR methods. CancellationToken is the built-in way of cooperatively cancelling async operations, tasks and threads

Comment: As for streaming events in general, check [Use streaming in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Streaming is supported through Channels

Comment: Ok, thank you for your feedback. I will check the articles.

Answer (score 0):

None of these things will work because a signalR hub is transient. This means it does NOT save any sort of state. This leaves you with 2 options:

1. You pass a cancellationtokensource from the client.
2. You look into memory caching, which is a state outside of the actual
   Hub.

Not sure which one of these are best practise, so if anyone could supply that information. That would help me as well!